# convert dictionary containing nested list of lists to df

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a dictionary containing what I think are called nested list of lists as shown below....

```
data = {'length': [[1633345896441, 101.25], [1633348822964, 101.67], [1633353200096, 102.32]], 'weight' : [[1633345896441, 7.09], [1633348822964, 7.44], [1633353200096, 7.51]]}
```

I am trying to convert to a single df as shown below....

```
             date   length    weight     
0    1633345896441  101.25      7.09   
1    1633348822964  101.67      7.44
2    1633353200096  102.32      7.51
```

However, I seem to be going in the wrong direction with my efforts so far...

```
k, v = list(data.items())[0]
df = pd.DataFrame(v).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Help much needed - please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'length': [[1633345896441, 101.25], [1633348822964, 101.67], [1633353200096, 102.32]],
        'weight' : [[1633345896441, 7.09], [1633348822964, 7.44], [1633353200096, 7.51]]}

df = pd.DataFrame({k : dict(v) for k, v in data.items()}).rename_axis("date").reset_index()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
            date  length  weight
0  1633345896441  101.25    7.09
1  1633348822964  101.67    7.44
2  1633353200096  102.32    7.51
```

Comment: sorry, in my example I only provided `length` and `weight` which is two items - how can I adapt for four items?

Comment: As you can see my solution does not depend on the number of items, keys in the dictionary. So it should work. Anyhow glad to test it if you can add a concrete example with four items perhaps

Comment: In fact it worked after I corrected a mistake on my end. Thank you immensely